# Why does this ruby statement, which subtracts two identical arrays, fail the .empty? test?

Tags: arrays, ruby, is-empty

In this snippet (from line 19 of https://github.com/bitfinexcom/bitfinex-api-rb/blob/master/lib/bitfinex/connection.rb - this is also the source for the class containing the check_params method definition.)

```
if (params.keys - allowed_params).empty?
```

`params.keys` is an array, and `allowed_params` is an array. Why does the subtraction fail the `.empty` test?

To set it up to repeat this:

```
$gem install bitfinex-rb pry
```

Ruby source

```
#!/opt/local/bin/ruby

# Annoying!
# Stuff is installed to $GEMPATH/bitfinex-rb-0.0.11
# But you have to invoke it as below.
require 'pry'
require 'bitfinex'

Bitfinex::Client.configure do |conf|
  conf.secret = ENV["BFX_API_SECRET"]
  conf.api_key = ENV["BFX_API_KEY"]
end

client = Bitfinex::Client.new

history_req = {
      'since' => 1444277602,
      'until' => 0,
      'limit' => 500,
      'wallet' => "exchange"
}

puts
print history_req.keys
puts
puts history_req.keys

client.history(
   currency = "USD",
   history_req
)
```

script output (with extra help from pry)

> $ pry wtf.rb  {"account"=>{"read"=>true, "write"=>false},
>   "history"=>{"read"=>true, "write"=>false}, "orders"=>{"read"=>true,
>   "write"=>true}, "positions"=>{"read"=>true, "write"=>false},
>   "funding"=>{"read"=>true, "write"=>true}, "wallets"=>{"read"=>true,
>   "write"=>false}, "withdraw"=>{"read"=>false, "write"=>false}}
>
> ["since", "until", "limit", "wallet"] since until limit wallet
>
> Exception: Bitfinex::ParamsError: Bitfinex::ParamsError
>   -- From: /opt/local/lib/ruby2.4/gems/2.4.0/gems/bitfinex-rb-0.0.11/lib/bitfinex/connection.rb
>   @ line 23 @ level: 0 of backtrace (of 22).
>
> ```
> 18:     # Make sure parameters are allowed for the HTTP call
> 19:     def check_params(params, allowed_params)
> 20:       if (params.keys - allowed_params).empty?
> 21:         return params
> 22:       else
> 23:         raise Bitfinex::ParamsError
> 24:       end
> 25:     end
> 26: 
> 27:     def rest_connection
> 28:       @conn ||= new_rest_connection ...exception encountered, going interactive! [71] pry(main)>
> ```

Source for the Bitfinex gem on github:

https://github.com/bitfinexcom/bitfinex-api-rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's a peek at the [docs for the `history` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/bitfinex-rb/Bitfinex/HistoricalDataClient#history-instance_method):

> #### Parameters:
>
> - **`currency`** (`string`) (*defaults to: "`usd`"*) — (optional) Specify the currency, default “USD”
> - **`params`** (*defaults to: `{}`*) — :since [time] (optional) Return only the history after this timestamp.
> - **`params`** (*defaults to: `{}`*) — :until [time] (optional) Return only the history before this timestamp.
> - **`params`** (*defaults to: `{}`*) — :limit [int] (optional) Limit the number of entries to return. Default is 500.
> - **`params`** (*defaults to: `{}`*) — :wallet [string] (optional) Return only entries that took place in this wallet. Accepted inputs
>     are: “trading”, “exchange”, “deposit”

So the allowed keys in `params` are `:since`, `:until`, `:limit`, and `:wallet`.

The keys in *your* `params` are `'since'`, `'until'`, `'limit'`, and `'wallet'`.

```
allowed_params = [:since, :until, :limit, :wallet]
params = {
  'since' => 1444277602,
  'until' => 0,
  'limit' => 500,
  'wallet' => "exchange"
}

params.keys - allowed_params
# => [:since, :until, :limit, :wallet]

(params.keys - allowed_params).empty?
# => false
```

The solution is to change your definition of `history_req` to use Symbol keys instead of Strings.

```
history_req = {
  since: 1444277602,
  until: 0,
  limit: 500,
  wallet: "exchange"
}
```

You can see where `allowed_params` comes from in [the `history` method's source](https://github.com/bitfinexcom/bitfinex-api-rb/blob/b298bf1ca7ada3d470d2d420f5434146e94e2143/lib/bitfinex/historical_data.rb#L15):

```
def history(currency="usd", params = {})
  check_params(params, %i{since until limit wallet})
  # ...
end
```

The construct `%i{...}` (note the `i`) [produces an array of Symbols](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings), ergo `[:since, :until, :limit, :wallet]`.

Comment: So, in other words the two "identical arrays" you subtract are in no way identical. They don't even contain values of the same type, let lone the same values.

Comment: To this ruby n00b, the significance of the ":" in the param definitions was not clear. I just thought they were some sort of side effect of using puts on a hash or something. Like trying to learn to fly a helicopter - too many things to keep moving at the same time :). Also, no explicit (explicit to me, that is) example was to be found :(